# Module not found error using Sequelize with angular-cli

Tags: mysql, angular, webkit, angular-cli

I've got an angular 2/4 app that I've set up with angular-cli (v 1.3.2). I have a MAMP mysql server running, which I can see in Sequel Pro.

To connect using sequelize, I followed the [getting started docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started). (And I installed [@types/sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sequelize).) But I'm getting `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve...` for the mysql and postgres dialects.

Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{

  public sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize;

  constructor(){
    this.sequelize = new Sequelize('local-db', 'username', 'password', {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
      }
    });
    this.init();
  }

  public init(){
    this.sequelize.authenticate()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:');
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
}
```

Maybe webpack might choke on some lazy loaded resources of 3rd party libraries (just guessing from [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6542))? So, I added sequelize as an external library in my .angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js"
]
```

But I'm getting the same errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/query.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tedious' in '[MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql'
resolve 'tedious' in '[MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/package.json (relative path: ./lib/dialects/mssql)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/package.json (relative path: ./lib/dialects/mssql)
    resolve as module
      [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      [MYAPPROOT]/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
yada
yada
yada
```

I see in the sequelize connection-manager.js, finding modules might be a problem:

```
if (err.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
    throw new Error('Please install \'' + (sequelize.config.dialectModulePath || 'pg') + '\' module manually');
  }
```

But I have mysql2 installed, per getting started directions.

So what is missing? Any help with this mystery would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "getting started" docs don't explicitly say so, but they're referring to a node.js application, not an angular one.  You almost certainly don't want to connect to SQL from your angular application.  You should create a "backend" node.js application which connects to your database and talk to that application from angular using some kind of API.

Technically it's possible to access mysql from angular, but that would require:

1. Putting your login credentials in the angular application.  Anyone
   who uses your application would be able to see them
2. When you put "localhost" in for the connection, that's the localhost of your
   browser which means it could only work if your browser and database
   are running on the same machine.